# Can we add bottom padding to Material3 ModalBottomSheet in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I was wondering if it was possible to add some spacing between the navigation bar and my ModalBottomSheet or do I have to use some other composable ?

Here's my code.

I've tried to add bottom padding in the modifier but it's not adding any space while top padding make the bottom sheet overlap on the navigation bar.

```
    ModalBottomSheet(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = MaterialTheme.spacing.small), // bottom padding doesn't work here
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.extraLarge,
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        dragHandle = { BottomSheetDefaults.DragHandle() },
    ) {
        
    }
```

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFusI.jpg)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a workaround using `BoxWithConstraint` with some padding and using `containerColor = Color.Transparent`. I also set the insets to `windowInsets = WindowInsets(0, 0, 0, 0)` so the scrim is applied to the whole screen:

```
ModalBottomSheet(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = MaterialTheme.spacing.small),
    shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.extraLarge,
    onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
    sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
    containerColor = Color.Transparent,
    dragHandle = null,
    windowInsets = WindowInsets(0, 0, 0, 0)
) {
    BoxWithConstraints(
        Modifier
            .navigationBarsPadding()
            .padding(bottom = 10.dp)
    ) {
        // Content here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding bottom padding through the modifier, you can try adding a spacer inside the content itself. So something like this:

```
ModalBottomSheet(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = MaterialTheme.spacing.small),
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.extraLarge,
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        dragHandle = { BottomSheetDefaults.DragHandle() },
    ) {
        ... other content ...
        Spacer(height = MaterialTheme.spacing.small)
    }
```

Comment: This will just add some blank space at the bottom of my sheet

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy of ModalBottomSheet except this accepts bottomOffset which is what you want and instead of a shape parameter it takes in a cornerRadius:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun EnhancedBottomSheet(
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    sheetState: SheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(),
    containerColor: Color = BottomSheetDefaults.ContainerColor,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(containerColor),
    tonalElevation: Dp = BottomSheetDefaults.Elevation,
    scrimColor: Color = BottomSheetDefaults.ScrimColor,
    dragHandle: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = { BottomSheetDefaults.DragHandle() },
    windowInsets: WindowInsets = BottomSheetDefaults.windowInsets,
    cornerRadius: Dp,
    bottomOffset: Dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(
                horizontal = MaterialTheme.spacing.large
            ),
        sheetState = sheetState,
        containerColor = containerColor,
        contentColor = contentColor,
        tonalElevation = tonalElevation,
        scrimColor = scrimColor,
        dragHandle = dragHandle,
        windowInsets = windowInsets,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(
            cornerRadius
        )
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    color = Color.Unspecified,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                        bottomStart = cornerRadius,
                        bottomEnd = cornerRadius
                    )
                )
                .clip(
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                        bottomStart = cornerRadius,
                        bottomEnd = cornerRadius
                    )
                )
        ) {
            content()
        }
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(bottomOffset)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            val cornerRadiusPx = cornerRadius.toPx()
            drawPath(
                path = Path().apply {
                    moveTo(0f, 0f)
                    lineTo(cornerRadius.toPx(), 0f)
                    arcTo(
                        rect = Rect(
                            offset = Offset(0f, -2*cornerRadiusPx),
                            size = Size(2*cornerRadiusPx, 2*cornerRadiusPx)
                        ),
                        startAngleDegrees = 90f,
                        sweepAngleDegrees = 90f,
                        forceMoveTo = false
                    )
                    close()
                },
                color = scrimColor,
                blendMode = BlendMode.Src
            )
            drawPath(
                path = Path().apply {
                    moveTo(size.width, 0f)
                    lineTo(size.width - cornerRadius.toPx(), 0f)
                    arcTo(
                        rect = Rect(
                            offset = Offset(size.width-2*cornerRadiusPx, -2*cornerRadiusPx),
                            size = Size(2*cornerRadiusPx, 2*cornerRadiusPx)
                        ),
                        startAngleDegrees = 90f,
                        sweepAngleDegrees = -90f,
                        forceMoveTo = false
                    )
                    close()
                },
                color = scrimColor,
                blendMode = BlendMode.Src
            )
            drawRect(
                topLeft = Offset.Zero,
                size = this.size,
                color = scrimColor,
                blendMode = BlendMode.Src
            )
        }
    }
}
```

### Code explanation

It's a little hard to explain how this works but I will try. We have a Box which contains only the content we need. This box has a modifier which clips the content to the desired cornerRadius only from bottom because the top has already been clipped by the ModalBottomSheet itself. Under this Box we have a Canvas which will add the bottomOffset. It draws a rectangle of color scrim(the color of the darkened background) with bottomOffset height with blendMode BlendMode.Src which only keeps the rectangle without the content behind. Now we removed the bottom rectangle part of the ModalBottomBar. We also need to remove the little "triangles"(one side of which is an arch) to ensure that the layout has cornerRadius at the bottom too. To do this we have to draw them on the Canvas. We are going to draw them using Path. Canvas can draw outside its bounds, so we are safe drawing these above the Canvas bounds. If you look at the logic of drawing them it is quite straightforward. The only thing that might need clarification is how the arcTo function works. First it takes in a rectangle which acts as the arc's bonuds if it were a full circle or an oval. StartAngleDegrees specifies where the arc should start. You can think of it like this: 0 is the 3 on the clock and as the angle increases we are moving clockwise on the clock. Then the sweepAngleDegrees specifies how much of the arc should be drawn and again in the clockwise direction. Hope this was clear)